# AngularJS + servlet + EJB (J2EE): is it a combination acceptable according to MVC pattern?

Tags: java, angularjs, servlets, model-view-controller

I'd like to create a web application according to MVC pattern. It should use Servlets as controller. EJB as components of the J2EE framework to implement the application login but instead to use JSTL and EL as languages to show datas on the views, I'd like to use AngularJS. Do you think it is a possible thing and most important a really convenient way to program?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is totally possible, you will write your html templates with angular, and then use the Servlets to return Json objects.
See these tutorials for instance :

- http://www.radcortez.com/?s=angular
- https://javatutorial.net/how-to-build-single-page-application-with-java-ee-and-angular

Edit: fixing links that became broken

Comment: I'd like to know if this could take some true advantages than using JSTL or EL

Comment: JSTL and EL would be more appropriate if you want to display data statically, without or with few ajax/javascript. You will have to send a new request and reload a whole jsp page after every action on your data to have the updated values reflected. However, if you want to update small chuncks of your page using ajax call, it is better to have AngularJS objects, and use the servlet to process and serve data.You can of course combine the two as well.